# How to make TypeScript understand which type i use

Tags: typescript

I have function

```
export const validateKushkiForm = (type: KUSHKI_METHODS, kushkiData: KushkiCashType | 
KushkiTransferType)
 => {

    const errors = [];

    if (type === KUSHKI_METHODS.CASH) {
        !kushkiData.firstName && errors.push('firstName');
        !kushkiData.lastName && errors.push('lastName');
        !kushkiData.documentNumber && errors.push('documentNumber');
    } else if (type === KUSHKI_METHODS.TRANSFER) {
        !kushkiData.documentNumber && errors.push('documentNumber');
    }

    return errors;
};
```

in KushkiCashType next type

```
firstName: string;
lastName: string;
documentNumber: string;
```

in KushkiTransferType

```
documentNumber: string;
```

```
Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'KushkiCashType | KushkiTransferType'.
  Property 'firstName' does not exist on type 'KushkiTransferType'.ts(2339)
```

kushkiData can have KushkiCashType or KushkiTransferType
how to fix this error?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w23Y1N)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you could use type extending

```
enum KUSHKI_METHODS {
  CASH,
  TRANSFER,
}

type KushkiCashType = {
  firstName: string
  lastName: string
  documentNumber: string
}
type KushkiTransferType = {
  documentNumber: string
}

export const validateKushkiForm = (
  type: KUSHKI_METHODS,
  kushkiData: KushkiCashType & KushkiTransferType
) => {
  const errors: string[] = []

  if (type === KUSHKI_METHODS.CASH) {
    !kushkiData.firstName && errors.push("firstName")
    !kushkiData.lastName && errors.push("lastName")
    !kushkiData.documentNumber && errors.push("documentNumber")
  } else if (type === KUSHKI_METHODS.TRANSFER) {
    !kushkiData.documentNumber && errors.push("documentNumber")
  }

  return errors
}
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: Yeeee, it's fixed error, thx
but did it fix TS? :D I mean, did we have some right decision to make it VAR 1 OR VAR 2

Comment: This isn't helpful, it makes it way harder to call the method with a KushkiTransferType because you have to add the missing fields.

Answer (score 1):

You have to determine the type based on the object in question. You can't determine the type of `b` from the value of `a`.

A typical approach would be to make it a property of the object:

```
type KushkiCashType = {
    type: 'cash';
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    documentNumber: string;
}

type KushkiTransferType = {
    type: 'transfer';
    documentNumber: string; 
}

export const validateKushkiForm = (kushkiData: KushkiCashType | 
KushkiTransferType) => {
    const errors = [];

    if (kushkiData.type === 'cash') {
        !kushkiData.firstName && errors.push('firstName');
        !kushkiData.lastName && errors.push('lastName');
        !kushkiData.documentNumber && errors.push('documentNumber');
    } else if (kushkiData.type === 'transfer') {
        !kushkiData.documentNumber && errors.push('documentNumber');
    }

    return errors;
};
```

---

Keeping closer to what you have, you could test properties of the object with `in`. In this case, since one type has `firstName` and the other does not, you can check for that.

```
type KushkiCashType = {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    documentNumber: string;
}

type KushkiTransferType = {
    documentNumber: string; 
}

export const validateKushkiForm = (kushkiData: KushkiCashType | 
KushkiTransferType) => {

    const errors = [];

    if ("firstName" in kushkiData) {
        !kushkiData.firstName && errors.push('firstName');
        !kushkiData.lastName && errors.push('lastName');
        !kushkiData.documentNumber && errors.push('documentNumber');
    } else {
        !kushkiData.documentNumber && errors.push('documentNumber');
    }

    return errors;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new definition that merges the two types together.

```
type NewType = KushkiCashType | KushkiTransferType;

export const validateKushkiForm = (type: KUSHKI_METHODS, kushkiData: NewType) => {
....
```

Seems like it should work the way that you have it but this might help.

Comment: Won't solve the error, since this is just a type alias.

Comment: @caTS Fair enough. Thanks for pointing that out.